# Exporting data programmatically from an application

Tags: iphone

In my iPhone application,i have a registration screen contains user name, address,Phone number etc. Now i need to export this data and mail it. How can i export the data programmatically from my screen.Any help?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps somewhere in your app you have:

```
UITextField *_usernameField;
```

Then something similar to:

```
NSString *_username = [_usernameField text];
NSURL *_mailURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:?subject=My Data&body=%@", _username]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:_mailURL];
```

will open the Mail app and create a new message with the subject "My Data" and a body that contains the text contents of the username text field. Just modify this to build the message you need to send.

Comment: Ok. I am saving data in an sqlite database. I need to export some datas from sqlite to CSV or sqlite format. How can i do this.